# Preventing Double/Duplicate HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, mean-stack

I have just realised this and i can't believe I didn't see this earlier. It seems like common sense and i can't believe I was such an idiot.

Basically I've realised that **double clicking** on any button that does **a HTTP POST** request in my MEAN Stack application generates 2 requests and duplication of data.

How do I prevent duplication of data? I would like to handle this Server side because that seems more secure and reliable but also any client side solutions will also be helpful.

I have already read a question on SO which talked about using **GUID** to prevent this but I couldn't really understand what they meant and how would I implement it.

Comment: Just use a boolean that you toggle once a post request is sent and once you get the reply. Then edit the POSTing code so it'll only create a POST request if no other request is pending.

Comment: remove / hide the button after click using javascript

Comment: @AnmolMittal Thank you for the comment. Yes I will be implementing this on the client side. But I would also like a server side solution just in case a user has JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Are you using session server side ?

Comment: @AnmolMittal Yes I am using Express.js Sessions to remember users state.

Comment: initialize a session variable (say flag) to 0,inside your middleware check if its zero , increment it and continue else end response

Comment: @AnmolMittal any chance you can explain this in detail as an answer? It'll be really helpful.

Comment: If you are working with xhr, better implement it on client side. before send request just check is xhr equal to null. When request finished, set xhr to null. Also, using this, you will be able to abort requests, if user need no anymore request data.

Answer (score 0):

Session variable is created Specific to user .

At server , create session variable initially :-

```
req.session.flag = 0
```

Inside your post middleware :-

```
router.post('/url',function(req,res,next){
  if(req.session.flag) res.send({data:'second time accessed'});
  else {
    req.session.flag = 1;
  //your code here 
  }
})
```

---

Destroy the session when user logs out or according to your need

Comment: Thank you so much. Will the session variable be created every time theres a new request by the user? And Im guessing I don't need to save the session flag permanently anywhere?

Comment: create it when you login the user,it is stored permanently until session exist

Comment: so basically create a session flag on login, when user does a POST check if flag is  0 increment it and run code. If flag is already 1 end response. But what if the user does another POST request for something different in the same session? The flag will still be 1 and its block it? Should I reset the flag to 0?

Comment: You never show clearing of the session variable which is equally important.  This also prevents the user from doing completely different operations at the same time in different windows which does not necessarily need to be prevented.

Comment: your condition is for that specific url only ,i.e post request on '/url'.post request of '/url2' will be handled differently